# Java file could not detect the xml file that i have created manually

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So i have created a xml file to implement cardview, but when i type R.layout.carview(my xml file name), it pops out error. It as me to create to create a new layout resource file with the same name which i already did.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cardview));
}
```

Can anyone answer my question as this is my assignment which deadline is nearby. Thanks ALOT !

Comment: What error it is showing exactly and also pl share your layout file.

Comment: once try ignoring that pop up and compile it